# Is it possible to find out the to and from fields in a solana transaction?

Tags: transactions

Hey I am working on a product that helps users analyze their solana transactions for tax purposes. I am wondering if there is a reliable way to tell who is the sender/from and who is the receiver/to in a transaction. I am thinking the easiest way to do this would be to look at the changes in the postBalance/preBalance and postTokenBalance/preTokenBalance, but is there another way like analyzing the instructions? What would be the ideal way to reliably get this information?

Answer (score 1):

in `transaction.message` you can find `accountKeys` those are the accounts for the `postBalance` and `preBalance` in order. This means the first `preBalance` and `postBalance` are for the first `account` in `accountKeys`.

**example**

doing this in rust, but it's gonna be similar in typescript since they both invoke the Solana JSON RPC API.

```
{
account_keys: [
    ParsedAccount {
        pubkey:  "9FunJaYzY97hcTNN95mAn8iEhXQjw9NpKDmng8NYLAbt",
        writable: true,
        signer: true 
    },
    ParsedAccount {
        pubkey: "CXFCTHyuhcJL3fiFR5eRochz4k9dwzZWfLMU7knzaCp",
        writable: true,
        signer: false
    }],
}
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense so basically the change in balance (post - pre) that is positive is the receiver and the change in balance that is the negative is the sender?

Comment: Yes that's correct